# Filtering a large dynamodb table for data analytics purposes

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We have a request come in from our compliance department asking us to scan a dynamodb table which has millions of records, we need to be able to filter all the records for approximately 1300 email addresses, the email address on this table is not the partition key and is a secondary global index.

This is not a one time request and we need to be able to repeat this process with minimal effort in future. That means the table might have grown in that time or the number of requested emails might be larger.

What would be the best approach to filter the data and only take the records related to these emails?

I can only think of the following two approaches, maybe utilizing a lambda or step functions if the work needs to be done in batches but am open to any scalable alternatives:

- should we export the whole table to S3 and then process that?
- go through each email and call dynamodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the emails are in a GSI. If the email is in the primary key for the GSI then the easiest solution is to call DynamoDB once for each email, and you can make these calls in parallel (but you may want to do them in chunks of 1000 to avoid throttles or exhausting file handles on your host).

If the email is not in the PK, then running a scan on the GSI, returning `KEYS_ONLY` can be ok depending on your table size and how often you run the task. If you have 10 million records with 1KB average record size in the GSI, this will cost $0.30 USD each time it is run. You can run a parallel scan to make it run fast. You can judge if the time/money tradeoff makes sense versus another solution that takes more engineering effort, such as exporting to S3.